# Tsung setdynvars not substituting value

Tags: tsung

I have the following script and for some reason the value is not being substituted with the value 1.

```
<sessions>
<session probability="100" name="connect_chat" type="ts_websocket">
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval" code="fun({Pid,DynVars}) ->
                  1 end.">
        <var name="cun" />
    </setdynvars>
 <request subst="true">
    <websocket type="connect" path="/uname=SampleUser%%_cun%%"/>
  </request> 
</session>
```

In fact the request to the uname at the server side is being received as follows:

SampleUser%_cun%

Any ideas of what can be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some bug in the path substitution process. This have solved my problem.

http://lists.process-one.net/pipermail/tsung-users/2013-July/002532.html